# How to add fonts to VcXsrv X-Server?

Tags: windows-10, fonts, windows-subsystem-for-linux, x-server, vcxsrv

I can't find any documentation on how to add new fonts to VcXsrv. I found [this](http://www.straightrunning.com/xmingnotes/fonts.php#head-11) but this is for a different program (Xming) and though I followed all the steps the fonts still doesn't show up in the X-server application (I'm trying with Terminator).

Any idea how to get it working?

Answer (score 1):

The author of VcXsrv himself answered part of this question [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/vcxsrv/discussion/986201/thread/b545aa2b/#acf8).

> Currently the default font path is
> `fonts/misc/,fonts/TTF/,fonts/OTF,fonts/Type1/,fonts/100dpi/,fonts/75dpi/,fonts/cyrillic/,fonts/Speedo/,built-ins`
>
> When you want to add an extra one, you should add it to this list and pass
> it on the command line with the `-fp` option:
>
> `-fp fonts/terminus-font/,fonts/misc/,fonts/TTF/,fonts/OTF,fonts/Type1/,fonts/100dpi/,fonts/75dpi/,fonts/cyrillic/,fonts/Speedo/,built-ins`
>
> The specified directories are relative to the directory where vcxsrv.exe is
> (default `C:\Program Files\vcxsrv`)
>
> You can also add the directory to the font path with the `xset +fp` command:
> `xset +fp fonts/terminus-font`

---

For using Windows 10 fonts, it might need a few more steps. The main steps of Xming to create `fonts.scale` and `fonts.dir` are still valid. When starting VcXsrv you should follow *marha*’s instructions in his answer and add `C:/Windows/Fonts,` within the `-fp` argument list. (Notice that you *must* use forward slash `/` instead of backward slash `\` in the path.)

If this still doesn’t work, try Cygwin/X. The performance is not as good as VcXsrv but it works well. Most of all, all the X tools are compatible to VcXsrv. You can use a lot of X command line tools (like `xset +fp ...`) to configure VcXsrv after it has started.

Comment: I don't know why this was down-voted because it seems like a good answer to me. Upvoting to rectify the situation.